# Is there a way to perform UPDATE with recursive LIKE operating on multiple rows?

Tags: sqlite, join, sql-update, sql-like

Given this tableA:

| pattern | data |
| --- | --- |
| abcxyz | 1 |
| abczys | 2 |
| jklabc | 42 |
| jkladc | 42 |

And another tableB:

| pattern | data |
| --- | --- |
| abc | 100 |
| jkl | 200 |

how do I construct a query that will transform the first table into:

| pattern | data |
| --- | --- |
| abcxyz | 100 |
| abczys | 100 |
| jklabc | 200 |
| jkladc | 200 |

Basically, `UPDATE tableA set tableA.data = tableB.data from tableB where tableA.pattern LIKE (SELECT tableB.pattern from tableB group by tableB.pattern) || '%'` but with LIKE accepting multiple rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct `UPDATE...FROM` syntax for SQLite 3.33.0+ is:

```
UPDATE tableA AS a 
SET data = b.data 
FROM tableB AS b
WHERE a.pattern LIKE b.pattern || '%';
```

Comment: This seemed to work, I will validate the results tomorrow, but it seemed to work!
I have no idea UPDATE FROM and LIKE will operate with multiple rows.

Comment: @rion this is SQLite's way to perform a join between tables in the UPDATE statement: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html#update_from

Comment: I previously used UPDATE FROM so I know it exists, but I didn't know that UPDATE FROM with LIKE will accept multiple rows.